# QEMU Virtual Machine: Creating a shared folder between Windows 10 (host) and Solaris 2.7 (guest)

Tags: virtual-machine, solaris, virtualization, qemu

I was wondering if anyone could give me wisdom on how to create a shared folder between my host machine (running Windows 10) and the virtual machine I created in qemu which is running Solaris 2.7. I need a way to get files in and out of the VM.

I've managed to "plug in" a folder as a virtual drive into the VM, using

```
-drive file=fat:rw:[folder],bus=0,unit=1,if=scsi,format=raw,media=disk
```

in the VM invocation. Solaris sees this as a disk, but I'm unsure where to go from here. I can't seem to format it because I don't know the "disk" geometry (apparently Solaris was very particular about this). I tried mounting the unformatted drive in Solaris but it wasn't able to do that either. I even tried giving it an entry in /etc/vfstab to see if I could get it to automount, but that didn't work either.

Is there a different way I should be mounting it? Or is there a trick to getting Solaris to use this virtual drive? I'm also open to other alternatives people are aware of for transferring files in/out of my VM, but since Solaris 2.7 is a rather old operating system, things like networking (for example) aren't trivial to set up (and even basic things like ssh are missing).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you can use dd to write/read a single tar file at a time on the shared disk. Not very convenient, but perhaps better than nothing until you get a better answer.

Comment: How would that work? I can't actually mount the drivespace to anywhere in Solaris, so it doesn't have a mount point that it can copy files to.

Comment: You don't need to mount it to use dd; you just write to the raw disk device in /dev. You said Solaris sees it as a disk, so I assume it appears in /dev.

Comment: It appears in dev, yes. /dev/dsk/c0t1d0s*

Comment: Any way you can have your Windows host export an NFS file system?  Assuming the Microsoft implementation of NFS properly supports NFSv2, the Solaris 27 guest should have no problem accessing that.